# Command Line Date Formatting Assistance

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line-arguments

I am running a report for my boss, and there were dates showing as `DD/MM/YYYY` (example: `18/06/2013`). What can I use in my command to change this to `MM/DD/YYYY`? I'm thinking SED but I am not sure.

Also, the date is the first element in the log I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 18/06/2013 | sed -r 's|(..)/(..)/|\2/\1/|'
06/18/2013
```